# How to AchartEngine view convert image

Tags: android, achartengine

I am draw pie graph using **achartEngine** library .How to Pie graph convert as images and store in sdcard.

```
GraphicalView mChartview;
// after draw pie graph....

Bitmap bitmap =mChartview.toBitmap()
String fileName = "test" + ".png";

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    fileName);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
```

But create 0 size image problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code for capturing,Here `mChart` is your `GraphicalView`

```
            Bitmap bitmap1;
            mChart.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mChart.getDrawingCache());
            mChart.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/DCIM/Camera");    
            myDir.mkdirs();
            String fname = "Image123.jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Just change JPEG to PNG to catch up to the 1990s C-;